# Asymmetric RSA PRNG Implementation Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, random, rsa, formula

I posted a question [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70998/asymmetric-csprng-where-the-public-key-only-works-backward) asking if it was possible to create a PRNG in which an asymmetric private key could advance the PRNG while the public key could only reverse the PRNG. DannyNiu suggested an approach using RSA keys, for which I am working on a proof of concept [here](http://jsfiddle.net/skibulk/xfu1vdnc/). After advancing and reversing the PRNG using this method, I expected the starting and ending states of the PRNG to be identical, but in my implementation, they are not. What am I doing wrong?

```
// requires BigInteger.min.js: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/
// Using 256-bit RSA keys for fast demo only
// Keys generated using script found here: // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

var rsaPrivateKey = bigInt("24776132865927824498491212731968501748100480067637351152890073639930475656193");
var rsaPublicKey = bigInt("74211765065553557319818035137797975277750578756934646327508787135523363995803");
var rsaModulus = 65537;

// Initial state for the PRNG
// Cannot be 0 or 1
var state = bigInt.randBetween(2, rsaModulus-1);
print("0: " + state.toString());

// Advance the PRNG 5x using the private key
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  state = state.modPow(rsaPrivateKey, rsaModulus);
  print(i + ": " + state.toString());
}

// Reverse the PRNG 5x using the public key
for (var i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
  state = state.modPow(rsaPublicKey, rsaModulus);
  print(i + ": " + state.toString());
}

function print(str){
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", str + "<br>\r\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `rsaModulus` and `rsaPublic` were swapped. The corrected code below seems to do what is needed.

```js
// requires BigInteger.min.js: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/
// Using 256-bit RSA keys for fast demo only
// Keys generated using script found here: // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)
var bigInt = require("big-integer");

var rsaPrivateKey = bigInt("24776132865927824498491212731968501748100480067637351152890073639930475656193");
var rsaModulus = bigInt("74211765065553557319818035137797975277750578756934646327508787135523363995803");
var rsaPublicKey = 65537;

// Initial state for the PRNG
// Cannot be 0 or 1
var state = bigInt.randBetween(2, rsaModulus-1);
print("0: " + state.toString());

// Advance the PRNG 5x using the private key
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  state = state.modPow(rsaPrivateKey, rsaModulus);
  print(i + ": " + state.toString());
}

// Reverse the PRNG 5x using the public key
for (var i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
  state = state.modPow(rsaPublicKey, rsaModulus);
  print(i + ": " + state.toString());
}

function print(str){
    console.log(str);
//  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", str + "<br>\r\n");
}
```

Produces output (in Node.js, I didn't test in a browser):

```
0: 3089889900716331070935914834855269746958619454008171918802934456826278805869
1: 29294271228731490548225349341396330182559853938616577145390725955076346471738
2: 26514699849481326763107659510545065888424675390354763649355047607623510843283
3: 43142677973722044074820378370391067407717125958268872808246349065241317072133
4: 36861272951268123086050613298534678401193075212756094490295892940224420130435
5: 6529151801265964225108415545430092089926156264721909235696182044061658877417
4: 36861272951268123086050613298534678401193075212756094490295892940224420130435
3: 43142677973722044074820378370391067407717125958268872808246349065241317072133
2: 26514699849481326763107659510545065888424675390354763649355047607623510843283
1: 29294271228731490548225349341396330182559853938616577145390725955076346471738
0: 3089889900716331070935914834855269746958619454008171918802934456826278805869
```